# Jquery Modal Forms with Struts 1.3

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, struts-1

I'm builing a web application using Struts 1.3 for a class project, and I'm having some problems with the AJAX compatibility of Struts 1.x (I hear 2.x is way better with AJAX and jQuery).

Thank you for the reply, this is the updated problem:

I'm currently using a jquery UI modal form in the same jsp, and want to send the form data to a Struts Action when the user presses "create new venue" using AJAX. How do I go about sending (and retrieving) the data between the form and the Struts action?

In other words, the connection between:

```
"Create new venue": function() {
$.ajax({
    url: "/registered/insertVenue.do",
    data: 
});
```

(this is the code for my sumbit button for the modal form, I don't know how to attach the data in a way for it to be readable by the Struts Action)

and the 'execute' method of the Struts Action (which returns an ActionForward or null).

Thanks again! :)

Comment: What class makes you use Struts 1?!

Comment: Yeah, I know, it's terrible! I'm gonna show your comment to my TA :P

Comment: (And I'm a committer... But Struts 1 is woefully out of date and makes it difficult than necessary to create modern, testable software.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing, if you want to return data outside of an `ActionForward`, you must `return null`. When Struts sees a null `ActionForward`, it doesn't execute the forward.

Once done, the following type design is what I used to create a JSON Response in Struts:

```
public interface Result {

    public void applyResult(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception;
}


public abstract class ResultBasedAction extends Action {

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        Result result = execute(mapping, form, request);
        if (result == null) {
            throw new Exception("Result expected.");
        }

        result.applyResult(request, response);
        //Finally, we don't want Struts to execute the forward
        return null;
    }

    public abstract Result execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception;
}


public class JsonResult implements Result {

    private JSONObject json;

    public JsonResult(JSONObject json) {
        this.json = json;
    }

    public void applyResult(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        response.getOutputStream().write(json.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
    }
}
```

All your AJAX related responses will implement the `ResultBasedAction` for action, and a `Result` for the data to be sent to the client.

On your ajax, you will just have to do an HTTP `GET`, passing all parameters on the URL. Make sure that the parameters matches your Struts `ActionForm` for the required `Action` class.

Comment: (Agreed, although I did actually say the null bit already.) +1 for example.

Comment: Ok, ran into another problem: when I try to send the AJAX using GET, and adding all parameters in the URL I get 404 not found for the action, what could be the reasons for that?

Comment: @Nicolay, you will have to create a new SO question. Commenting won't help as there are plenty of information that is required (which won't fit on comment).

Comment: Thanks! New question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223167/jquery-modal-form-ajax-to-struts-1-3-action

Answer (score 3):

The backing framework really doesn't make much of a difference in terms of raw JavaScript/jQuery/Ajax.

You can return whatever you want from your Struts 1 action. If you want some JSON back like with a status or Flash message you can either write it directly to the response and return `null` instead of an `ActionForward`, or craft a JSP to have the content you want and set an appropriate header.

How the return value of the Ajax request is handled is all up to the client-side code: Struts 1 doesn't care what type of request it is; it will just spit back whatever it's configured to spit back.