# jQuery modal form AJAX to Struts 1.3 Action

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts-1

Making a new question, as was suggested to me.

I'm trying to send data from a jQuery UI modal form to a Struts ActionForm using AJAX. The URL looks something like this (using HTTP GET):

```
localhost.../insertVenue.do?param1=param1&param2=param2...
```

However, when I try to to do this I get 404 not found. /insertVenue.do is found, but not the URL with the extra parametres.

Hope anyone can shed some light on the issue!

This is what my struts-config.xml looks like (for the specific action):

```
<action path="/registered/insertVenue" type="actions.InsertVenueAction" name="venueFormInsert"></action>
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Post your `venueFormInsert` `ActionForm` code.

Comment: I actually got it to work, turned out it was a bug in our struts-config.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define a Form Bean to carry the values of your parameters in your struts-config.xml. In your example above you have mentioned "venueFormInsert". You'll want something like this...

```
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="venueFormInsert" type="forms.venueFormInsert" />
</form-beans>
```

Then define this Java Bean to match your expected parameters

```
public class JmsMessageForm extends ActionForm {

    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   
}
```

Other than that you havent stated what the actual URL you are using. It must have the context root included and the "path" you listed above from your struts-config.xml. So something like this if your appication's context root is called "myapp" when deployed...

http://server.acme.com/myapp/registered/insertVenue.do?id=5

This venueFormInsert bean will then be passed automatically to your action handler InsertVenueAction.execute() and be populated with the URL parameters passed in

Answer (score 0):

your url is not well formatted.

```
localhost.../insertVenue.do?param1=param1?param2=param2..
```

must be like

```
localhost.../insertVenue.do?param1=param1&param2=param2..
```

Comment: Bah, sorry about that. I've edited my question - my URL was actually well formatted, I just wrote it incorrectly in my question (guess I was tired!)